# CKNotificationInfo soundName does not work

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Sbuscription is create like below. It works, but no sound generated, why? Doc says: `if you specify the string default for this property, the system plays the default alert sound.`

```
let s2 = CKSubscription(recordType: recordType, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "destination = %@", CKReference(recordID: CKRecordID(recordName: loggedInUserSettingRecordName!), action: .DeleteSelf)), options: .FiresOnRecordCreation)
s2.notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
s2.notificationInfo.alertBody = " "
s2.notificationInfo.soundName = "default"
subscriptionsToSave.append(s2)
```

---

```
s2.notificationInfo.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
```

also not works

Answer (score 0):

Need to update `registerUserNotificationSettings` method call too.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Sound | .Alert, categories: nil))
```